# kendoListBox is not a function

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm trying to use the following Kendo example in my project, but I get an error says:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoListBox is not a function

```
<select id="listbox"></select>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#listBox").kendoListBox({
            dataSource: [
                { name: "Jane Doe" },
                { name: "John Doe" }
            ],
            template: "<div>#:name#</div>",
            toolbar: {
                tools: [ "moveUp", "moveDown", "remove" ]
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included kendo javascript on the page?

Comment: @rishipuri, I copied the code from the link "http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/listbox/overview". If you check this link you can see that the example not working itself. Why?

Comment: This [getting started](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/getting-started) link should help you.

Answer (score 3):

ListBox is a new Widget released in [Kendo UI R2 2017](http://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/kendo-ui-r2-2017).

You are probably using an older version of the kendo framework.

Answer (score 1):

Check to ensure you have not included `jQuery` [more than once](http://developmentsimplyput.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/how-make-sure-jquery-is-loaded-and-only.html) in your page (or any parent pages).

If this isn't the problem, ensure you have included all [required Kendo Javascript files](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites#javascript-prerequisites).

Comment: thank you so much , I spent lot of hours and I couldn't find the problem . I added jquery two times.